# Python Key Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-2.7

I'm having a Python Key Error and haven't been able to sort it out.

The error that is given is shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
import handling_data_
File "C:\Python27\handling_data_.py", line 453, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python27\handling_data_.py", line 443, in main
pans.append([row[0],p.classify(row)])
File "C:\Python27\handling_data_.py", line 367, in classify
cgclass = self.greater_class_prob_dist[query[2]]
KeyError: ' Without-pay'
```

The line in question is

```
clclass = self.less_class_prob_dist[query[2]]
```

I amen't sure what wrong with this line as there is another line for greater_class_prob_dist

```
cgclass = self.greater_class_prob_dist[query[2]]
```

The class is a naive bayes implementation, it works prefectly if take the entries from the text file which contain ' Without-pay' otherwise it does not.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Here is a link to the whole class and textfiles if people need to look at it or run it to see the problem for themselves
[Source Code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21608326/Naive_bayes.zip)

Any help much appericated

EDIT:
print of record contains ' Without-pay'

```
['tst1249', 62, ' Without-pay', 170114, ' Assoc-acdm', 12, ' Married-civ-spouse', ' Farming-fishing', ' Husband', ' White', ' Male', 0, 0, 50, ' United-States', '?']
```

Comment: Are you sure the acceptable key is `' Without-pay'` and not `'Without-pay'`?

Comment: Post the relevant portion of your source code here, so anyone could see what your code entails, even on a mobile device.

Comment: Yeah it is ' Without-pay' in the text file there is a space before each word.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything, you'll need to `.strip()` those leading spaces. Even though using `.split()` will auto-remove them.

Comment: Well, I ran your code and I didn't get a KeyError, I got an IndexError. I fixed that, then I got a bunch of ZeroDivisionError issues from the make_gaussian function. I seem to be having different issues with the code than you are o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at all the entries in `trainingset.txt`, you'll see that all the entries with `Without-pay` are listed as having `<=50k` income. As you can see in `__init__`, the training data is split into two groups:

```
        for row in data:
              if row[15] == ' >50K':
                    self.greaterThan_data.append(row)
              else:
                    self.lessThan_data.append(row)
```

Since none of the `Without-pay` entries have `>50k` income, none of them go into `greaterThan_data`.

So when you call...

```
        self.greater_class_prob_dist = self.getCatProbs(self.greaterThan_data,2)
```

..the resulting dict lacks that key.

Comment: No it works prefectly when take ' Without-pay' records out of the queries.txt file. When try the above code still have same problem

Comment: @Droid_Interceptor, OK, I looked a little harder and here's what I came up with.