# Python key error in function

Tags: python

I have a function that should return the number of words that contain each vowel (all lowercase), but I keep getting a **key error**. I'd appreciate any help in figuring it out. Thank you.

```
def vowelUseDict(t):
    '''computes and returns a dictionary with the number of words in t containing each vowel
    '''
    vowelsUsed = {}
    strList = t.split()
    newList = []
    vowels ='aeiou'
    for v in vowels:
        for strs in strList:
            if v in strs and strs not in newList:
                newList.append(strs)
                vowelsUsed[v] = 1
            if v in strs and strs in newList:
                vowelsUsed[v] += 1
    return vowelsUsed
text = 'like a vision she dances across the porch as the radio plays'
print(vowelUseDict(text))
#{'e': 5, 'u': 0, 'o': 4, 'a': 6, 'i': 3}
```

Comment: i would use a defaultdict or a Counter from collections. That would simplify this mess...

Comment: Do you uinderstand what a KeyError is?  [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print the data in the except suite. It should give you an idea of what is happening - work *backwards* from there.

Comment: `vowelsUsed[v] += 1` is probably the statement that is producing the error; `v` must not be a key.  That means you have a fallacy in the conditional `if v in strs and strs in newList:`

Comment: @wwii yes, hence the collections.Counter object that saves this broken logic

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ... unless the intent is to learn how to translate *logic* into code.

Comment: anyway, OP is probably trying his luck on some other forum right now. Best would be to close. I already did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Key Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260953/python-key-error)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def vowelUseDict(t):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    cnt = sum(map(Counter, t.split()), Counter())
    return {k: cnt[k] if k in cnt else 0 for k in vowels}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `newList` keeps the words from the previous vowels. Once you reach "like" for "i", it already exists since it was added for "e". This means that it tries to add to the value for key "i" in `vowelsUsed`, which doesn't exist (it would get added the first time a word is found *that hasn't been added for another vowel*).

Since (judging by the last line) you want every vowel to be in the resulting dict, you can just create the dict with all the vowels as keys and the values as zero, and you don't even have to check if a key exists. Just increase the value by one if the word contains the vowel.

The resulting code would be something like this:

```
def vowelUseDict(t):
    '''computes and returns a dictionary with the number of words in t containing each vowel
    '''
    strList = t.split()
    vowels ='aeiou'
    vowelsUsed = {v: 0 for v in vowels}
    for v in vowels:
        for strs in strList:
            if v in strs:
                vowelsUsed[v] += 1
    return vowelsUsed
text = 'like a vision she dances across the porch as the radio plays'
print(vowelUseDict(text))
#{'e': 5, 'u': 0, 'o': 4, 'a': 6, 'i': 3}
```

*Roy Orbison singing for the lonely; hey, that's me and I want you only*